# How to translate java "?" operator in C#?

Tags: c#, java

I would like to know the translation of this java code in C#

```
n = (length > 0) ? Math.min(length, buffer.length) : buffer.length;//Java code
```

Can it be equivalent to this in C# ?

```
if(length >0)
{
   n = Math.min(length, buffer.length);
}
else
{
   n = buffer.length;
}
```

Comment: You dont have to "translate" anything! That peace of code in Java is the same as in C# (`?` operator). You are probably having a trouble with `length`. To get the arrays length in C# you would write: `buffer.Length`. And it is `Math.Min()`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

C# has the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) as well.

In C#:

```
n = (length > 0) ? Math.Min(length, buffer.Length) : buffer.Length;
```

The only difference would be that method names are normally capitalized in .NET ([PascalCase](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PascalCase), instead of [camelCase](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CamelCase)).

If you are going to be working with C#, I suggest taking a look at the [available operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx).

Comment: I used to call it the ternary operator. Wikipedia teaches me that is a generic name for it.. you have it right. +1 for that.

Comment: @Gishu - a ternary operator is one that has 3 operands. The conditional operator is an example (the only one?) of a ternary operator. Many operators are binary operators (`+`, `-` etc), and some are unary operators (`++`, `--`).

Answer (score 1):

C# also has the ?: conditional operator, so no conversion is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

sure, but you can use the exact same expression also in C#

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but just use the same [syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

No need, the sytnax is exactly the same.

Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), should help you out :)

Answer (score 0):

```
n = (length > 0) ? Math.Min(length, buffer.Length) : buffer.Length;
```

Ternary operator exist in c# the only difference is that `Math.min` is `Math.Min` and `buffer.length` is `buffer.Length`

Comment: It's called the conditional operator, a ternary operator is just one with 3 operands